# SQL IN statement "inclusiveness"

Tags: sql

I'm not a programmer, but trying to learn.  I'm a nurse, and need to pull data for medical referral tracking from a database.  I have a piece of GUI software which builds JOIN queries for me to pull things from the database.  One of the operators I can use in the drop-down is "IN."  The referral documentation is stored in the table as codes made up of one to three letters.  For example, the code for a completed dental referral is CDF, and the code for a dental referral is D.

I want to build a report to allow other nurses to pull all their outstanding referrals, so I'll want to pull "D" but not "CDF"

If I use IN as the operator, and set my parameters to 'S','D','BP' {etc}  will that also pull the records which have the other, longer codes which contain those same letters? (like CDF, CSR, CBP)

I don't want to test it because I only have access to the production database, and I don't want to hose up actual patient records.  Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Short answer, no. But that doesn't mean your query won't lock your database and take a long time to execute. Which would depend on the size of the database, indexes and load. I suggest that you don't learn using the production database.

Comment: I suggest you post the SQL code generated by that program. What you see as an "IN" operator may be translated to "IN" or to "OR" but without code we can just guess...

Comment: you can't break records by querying a database.  you need to be able to add new records, update existing records, or delete existing records to hose it up.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the column that holds the referral code holds one and only one code per record (which is what it sounds like) the query should  function as you want and will not attempt to match substrings.

In any event, there's no danger that a query in the form `IN ('S', 'D', 'BP')` will match substrings.  To perform substring matches in SQL you have to use the `LIKE` operator.

The situation in which this will *not* work is if the referral code column holds multiple codes separated by commas.  This is an all-too-common mistake in designing databases but if the product you're using is commercial rather than home-grown, I think it's very unlikely to be the case.  If it is, searching it is much more difficult.

Comment: Perfect, thanks!  There are no commas or spaces or anything, just c set of characters in each cell.  And, to the commenters, thanks as well for the tips!